# How to call standalone C++/CLI function from C# code?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I googled for it already but all I can find is more "sophisticated" examples with classes and calling methods. What I need is just pure function.

So I have solution with 2 projects -- C++/CLI and C#. In the first one I have a function `HelloWorld`, in second I added reference to the first project, I called `HelloWorld` -- and I got compile error, `HelloWorld` is not found.

What I have to do with this function to be able to call it? The examples with classes looked pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class as seen in the tutorials and then let it have a static function. You cannot have free functions in C#. The function you created in C++ is just that... a C++ function without any CLI involved.

Comment: Sometimes "simple" is the new impossible :-) Thank you.

Comment: @greenoldman I don't think a single class with a single method is "sophisticated".

Comment: @Mephy, quotes matter.